# Actionscript 3, loading image from web

Tags: actionscript-3, image, air, urlloader

I'm trying to load an external image into my air app.

[CODE HERE (http://pastie.org/2314164)](http://pastie.org/2314164)

xml.artist_pic is pointing to image example: http://www.example.com/image.jpg
GLOBAL.skin.albumArt is a movie clip which inside has bitmap.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `Loader` class instead of `URLLoader`

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
   var image:Bitmap = (Bitmap)(e.target.content);
}
```

Comment: also, it is a good practice to name your attributes with lower starting letters.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here, so... (: